# React peer dependencies and package's react version restriction

Tags: reactjs, peer-dependencies

My react project depends on "react": "^16.8.4".

It also uses react-circular-color@1.3.0

However, while building, I get this warning.

react-circular-color@1.3.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed.

Does this mean, my project's main dependency on react should be restricted to ^15.0.0?
Or How do I satisfy the peer dependency of different packages?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that if your project run correctly

Answer (score 0):

If a library provides versions in `peerDependency`, it means that it's tested and supposed to work with those versions. Usually the caret `^` is used to allow minor updates (e.g. 15.0 to 15.1), which add features, but never break their API.

If you decide to install another major version (15 to 16), it's on your own risk. Hopefully you can rely on automated regression tests in that case, because the library has not been tested with that new API.